# Image parameters for setting cursor in Java Swing

Tags: java, image, swing, cursor

I have troubles with displaying custom cursor in Java Swing app.

I set the cursor by this code:

```
Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
Image image = toolkit.getImage("sword.png");
Point hotSpot = new Point(0,0);
Cursor cursor = toolkit.createCustomCursor(image, hotSpot, "Sword");
panel.setCursor(cursor);
```

This image(size: 32x32px) is displayed quiet correctly(only rubber colour goes from grey to yellow):

[image]

but this image(size: 128x128) is displayed incorrectly - smaller than 128x128(probably 64x64) and without some colours:
[image]

This happened when i run the app on Linux Ubuntu.

When i run the app on Windows(tested on Win 8) the pencil image is displayed without any problems and sword image with slightly distorted colours. Both of them have same size(32x32).

**My question is - what parameters should an image for setting cursors have (size, type, quality, number of colours) and if it depends on Java Swing or particular OS? And if i should set cursor in another way, because my code is incorrect.**

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that most of the OS want a size of 32x32, if it's bigger it will try to resize it to the correct size, so it can happens that it isn't displayed correctly. So you could assume that the correct size should be 32x32.

You could use:

```
getBestCursorSize(int preferredWidth, int preferredHeight)
```

It returns the closest supported cursor dimension of the desired size. Take a look in the API =>
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getBestCursorSize%28int,%20int%2

As a good and safe solution you should just resize your Image with Photoshop, GIMP or another good program, to the size which is supported.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tested `getBestCursorSize(128, 128)` - which is size of sword image, that returned me closest supported dimension 64 x 64. So i changed size of that image in GIMP to 32x32 and 64x64 and tested both of them, but the problem with displaying colours of that image remains(but looks better than toolkit implementation resize). Also it looks a little bit different, when i export image in GIMP as gif or png type. Do you think, it could be a problem with the type of that image or its number of colours? I am beginner in issues of graphics.

Comment: Some OSs (looking at you Windows) may also "truncate" the image instead.

Comment: @Petr.M It's possible that under some OSs (like windows), the cursor only supports 256 colors, the image may be getter dithered to support this...